# Passing a string from C to Python to multiprocessing without making an extra copy

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-c-api

I have a C application that embeds the Python 2.7 interpreter. At some point in my program, a potentially large string (`char*`) is generated and needs to be processed by some Python code. I use `PyObject_CallFunction` to call the Python function and pass the string as an argument. This Python function then uses the `multiprocessing` library to analyze the data in a separate process.

Passing the string to the Python function will create a copy of the data in a Python `str` object. I tried to avoid this extra copy by passing a `buffer` object to the Python function. Unfortunately, this generates an error in the `multiprocessing` process during unpickling:

`TypeError: buffer() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

It seems as though `buffer` objects can be pickled, but not unpickled.

Any suggestions on passing the `char*` from C to the `multiprocessing` function without making an extra copy?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly this could be implemented in your situation, but try using ``multiprocessing.sharedctypes`` somehow. I used it to to pass the data between python processes without copy

Comment: Would it be preferable to write it to a pipe or other file resource and pass a handle to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach that worked for me:

Before you create your big C string, allocate memory for it using Python:

```
PyObject *pystr = PyString_FromStringAndSize(NULL, size);
char *str = PyString_AS_STRING(pystr);
/* now fill <str> with <size> bytes */
```

This way, when the time comes to pass it to Python, you don't have to create a copy:

```
PyObject *result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(callable, pystr, NULL);
/* or PyObject_CallFunction(callable, "O", pystr) if you prefer */
```

Note that you shouldn't modify the string once this is done.